# cordova-plugin-firebase with phonegap build

Tags: firebase, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I am making a hybrid app with Phonegap. Till now everything was fine.
However I am stuck with one plugin [cordova-plugin-firebase][1].

I have completed app with these codes:
Added this in my config.xml

```
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="2.0.2" />

 <platform name="android">
      <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
    </platform>
```

And have also added `google-services.json` in root and uploaded in phonegap build. But got following error:

```
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: cordova-google-play-services/kyg-google-play-services_lib
Running command: /project/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /project/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
    at build_9hhlfo8un5w66frpzrj124qfu.run(/project/build.gradle:157)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/project/cordova-plugin-firebase/kyg-build.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'project'.
> Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.997 secs
Command finished with error code 1: /project/gradlew cdvBuildDebug,-b,/project/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
Error: /project/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/project/cordova-plugin-firebase/kyg-build.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'project'.
> Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/project/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)




  [1]: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase
```